# Testing the Google Smart Home Action

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I have developed and released Smart Home Action,
Now I need to test it because I will modify that Action.

It will be a test with Actions on Google Project with released actions,
If I enable test,
Is it okay to understand that the following is displayed in the list of Smart Home Actions and can be used separately?
Does not it affect the released Action?

[the list of Smart Home Actions]

- [test] xxx Action  ←Test Action
- xxx Action         ←Released Action

If you know of this,please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the "Test Action" is intended to reflect the current console configuration and any changes you make there will not affect production. **However**, Smart Home works a little differently than other Action types in ways that affect this behavior (we are working to improve this).

Once your Action is deployed to production, the project will no longer reflect console changes to the test agent until those changes are submitted and reviewed. The recommended way to work around this constraint is to create a second project in the Actions console that you can use to test/validate your change.

When you're ready to submit the updates to production, you can follow the steps outlined to updating your existing production project in [Launching your smart home Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/launching).