# Can't modify deployed smart home action

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

**our project "XY" is certified and deployed in production**. We are migrating our production from bare metal to cloud platform. In the process we are changing DNS and domain. The only changes we are trying to achieve are update fulfillment and linking endpoints for this project.

According to: https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/launching#modify-action
We must go through 3 stages:

1. **Resubmit your test suite results.**
2. Fill out a new certification request form.
3. Resubmit your Action for review.

The first phase is not accomplishable:
In order to run the test suite:

- A) Enabled device testing for current draft. (Success)
- B) **Link action to your google account using the same account you used to sign in to the actions console.** (failed)

Why does the "B" fail ?
*Enabling current draft for testing do not reflect changes in the fulfillment and linking endpoints.
During the linking process in the Google Home app there is no option to select draft under the [test] prefixed section. I can only see linking for the deployed version which is already certified but has old endpoints to fulfillment and linking. The test suite has no relevance against the deployed version. I want to test against the current draft.*

I've come across the same problem:
[Testing the Google Smart Home Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360166/testing-the-google-smart-home-action)

**What can I do for resubmit test suite results ?**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing this out, we are working to improve this process.

For testing of your new configuration, I'll bring over part of the answer from the question you linked:

> Once your Action is deployed to production, the project will no longer reflect console changes to the test agent until those changes are submitted and reviewed. The recommended way to work around this constraint is to create a second project in the Actions console that you can use to test/validate your change.

For deploying production, I would recommend resubmitting your new Action version for review **without using the test suite**. During review, the certification team will reach out to you and work with you on the fact that this is an update to an existing Action.